# How do I adjust a hover image so that it is always full screen?

Tags: html, css, image, fullscreen

I'm setting up an image that would change when you hover over it. I want the image to be adjustable so that it is full screen on any screen. Instead of putting a pixel size I tried to put a percentage size, but nothing shows up. Is there a better way to get that done?

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .urlImg { 
        display:block; 
        width: 1000px;
        height: 848px;
        background-image: url('01.jpg'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        } 
    .urlImg:hover { 
        background-image: url('02.jpg'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <center><a href="main.html" class="urlImg" title="Come inside!"></a></center>
  </body>
```

Comment: If you want to expand the image on hover (so that it covers the full view), use the `position: fixed;` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size` combined with width and height of 100% (make sure the body extends to 100% as well):

```css
.urlImg {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 848px;
  background-image: url('http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.urlImg:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0}
```

```html
<a href="main.html" class="urlImg" title="Come inside!"></a>
```

(see it on the Full Page as well)

You can also play with absolute or fixed positioning (as @abhishek mention in the comment) to make it behave the similar way.